# Countdown to next month - progress bar - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, progress-bar

I am very new to HTML and have found a few tutorials online on how to make progress bars for various uses - but have found nothing for long time countdowns; (One day to another day).

I want a progress bar countdown to next month. E.g, if today was April 15, the progress bar would be 50% filled, since the next month is 15 days away.

Ideally, the countdown will start on the left using a specific time on a certain day as a starting point and move toward the right as time continues - arriving at the end when the countdown is up and the time on the specific second date has arrived. The time should also be specific to EST not the local time on the computer.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to:

- #### Calculate how many days until the next month.

  This is achieved by getting the current date (via the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) constructor) and getting the current month (with [`Date.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)), then constructing a new date via the `Date` constructor and adding `1` to the current month index. This is what `nextMonth` is in the example below.
- #### Calculate the number of days between the next month and the current day

  This is slightly more tricky. You'll have to get the millisecond difference between the two dates (by subtracting the results returned by [`Date.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) for the current date and the next month), then dividing by 1000 (to get the seconds), 60 (for minutes), 60 again (for hours), and finally dividing by 24 (for days).
- #### Calculate the number of days in the current month

  This is done by setting the month to one month later than the current month, and the date to `0`. Why? When 0 is provided for `dayValue`, the date will be set to the last day of the previous month, and since we set the month to the next month, it will return the last day of the current month. Calling [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) then returns the day of the month.

---

To make the progress bar, you can simply use the [`<progress>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress). Set the maximum to the number of days in the current month and the value to the number of days minus the days until the next month (how many days have passed in this month so far).

```js
const now = new Date();
const nextMonth = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 1);
const diffDays = Math.ceil(Math.abs(nextMonth.getTime() - now.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
now.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 1);
now.setDate(0);
const daysInCurrentMonth = now.getDate();
progress.max = daysInCurrentMonth;
progress.value = daysInCurrentMonth - diffDays;

/* below for debug purposes only */

console.log('Days in current month: ' + daysInCurrentMonth);
console.log('Days until next month: ' + diffDays);
```

```css
#progress {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<progress id="progress"></progress>
```

Comment: Of course! 

One more question: what if the start and end dates are not the 1st of each month? For example maybe July 16 as a start date and the end date August 16th?

It's my understanding that daysInCurrentMonth would only be usable for a countdown spanning one single month not continuing into another?

Comment: @mp32001 If the start date was July 16, the end date would be August 1st, since the code gets the current month index, adds one, and sets the date to 1.